# Edit OSX Keyboard Buffer

Tags: macos, keyboard-events

I’ve got a MacBook Pro with the [double-typing problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7754550) (and no, not a [cleanliness problem](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205662)) , and since apple wants north of $1000 to replace the keyboard, I’m hoping for a software solution.

Specifically, there are a handful of keys on my keyboard which frequently insert two characters per click, and I’m willing to bet that most of the time they are inserted into the keyboard buffer within a couple milliseconds -- which is faster than I could possibly type. Hence, I’m wondering if it’s possible to identify when a key has been “pressed” twice in the span of, say, 5ms, and delete the second keystroke.

I'm happy to do the work to code up a solution, but I'm not sure if it's even possible, so I'm looking for some guidance as to what software is even capable of editing the keyboard bbuffer. Automator? Apple Script? Something else?

Comment: There's probably not a viable software solution. You wouldn't be able hold down any keys based on your proposed suggestion... and there would likely be so much lag whenever the function kicked in that you'd get tired of it really quick.

Comment: holding down keys is different.  There are separate [keyup and keydown events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html).  I'm talking about catching a keydown-keyup-keydown-keyup all in the span of a couple milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, but think about the keys you tap quickly on a regular basis ( delete, numbers, return, etc.) — You don't think that would have the same side effects?

Comment: Sure, but my fastest double click is about 120 milliseconds between clicks.  I could safely debounce anything faster than say 80 milliseconds and probably catch 99% of the false double key presses.  Keep in mind that the issue is a mechanical debouncing problem, which happens *much* faster than double clicking.